# How to convert UTF8 to UTF16 in Firebird

Tags: utf-8, firebird, utf-16, utf

What ways do you know to convert UTF8 to UTF16. Maybe even through UDF functions. Well, you can also write in general about how to use UTF16 in Firebird?

Comment: What specifically do you need? Why is it even required for you? https://xyproblem.info

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, because Firebird doesn't support UTF16 as a character set. If you want to convert data in UTF-8 to UTF-16, you will have to do that in your client application, not in Firebird.

In theory you could do it using a UDF (deprecated) or UDR (replacement for UDF), but from the perspective of Firebird it would just be binary data, so doing this within Firebird wouldn't be very useful in my opinion.

Comment: In what sense `doesn't support UTF16` ? Is it possible to store UTF 16 characters (`char16_t` ) in firebird ? If so, what is the problem to create a UDF function that will convert a string from UTF8 to UTF16, and decode UTF16 to UTF8.

Comment: @ДенисКустов Firebird doesn't have a UTF-16 character set, so in that sense it is not supported, and neither can it convert UTF-8 to UTF-16 by itself. Trying to use UTF-16 is therefor awkward (you'd only have binary comparison, no collations, no conversion to other character sets) and hard to use. Sure, if you really want to you could solve it with UDF or UDR, but that doesn't make the hard fact go away that it would be awkward to use within Firebird itself, so you'd be better off not doing it within Firebird, and do the appropriate conversions in your client application.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i am not sure, but i think if you do CHARSET=NONE connection, then modern tools (Java, .Net, Delphi/Unicode) all send UTF-16 texts in and out. I thought there is at least a de facto support for UTF-16 on client libraries/protocols level, if not on the SQL engine level.

Comment: @Arioch'The No, they definitely do not. Jaybird will use the platform default character set (usually UTF-8 on Linux, Windows depends; Java 18+ always uses UTF-8 as platform default), and as far as I'm aware similar rules apply for the Firebird ADO.net provider.